# Can't connect to NodeJS server from Angular Frontend

Tags: node.js, angular, postgresql

I'm working on an Angular app, which connects to postgresql and make a simple operations on it. On Virtual Machine everything works perfectly, but when I started to test it on official server things goes worse.

My Angular Frontend works great, everything shows up etc but when I'm going to login, when I press the button there are this error in console:

```
zone.js:2969 OPTIONS http://192.168.30.5:3132/auth/login
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

My Frontend works on port 4200 and I start it with

```
ng serve --host=192.168.30.5
```

NodeJS server starts with just

```
node server.js
```

I've checked netstat -nltp and it shows:

```
192.168.30.5:4200   0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    20597/ng serve --ho
:::3132             :::*         LISTEN    20665/node-default
```

I tried to test other address combinations (Use localhost instead of 192.168.30.5, use 0.0.0.0 instead, use 127.0.0.1 etc) and nothing worked.

One thing that I saw is, when I use address 192.168.30.5, the error is

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

but when I use localhost, error changes to

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I expect this app to work like on the VM, so when I, fo example, click the login button, it logs me in instead of showing error in console. I would be grateful for any help.

My server.js file:

```
console.log("NodeJS Activated");
(function () {

  'use strict';

  const app = require('./app');
  const debug = require('debug')('herman-express:server');
  const http = require('http');

  const port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3132');
  app.set('port', port);

  const server = http.createServer(app);
  server.listen(port);
  server.on('error', onError);
  server.on('listening', onListening);

  function normalizePort(val) {
    const port = parseInt(val, 10);
    if (isNaN(port)) {
      return val;
    }
    if (port >= 0) {
      return port;
    }
    return false;
  }

  function onError(error) {
    if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
      throw error;
    }
    const bind = typeof port === 'string' ? 'Pipe ' + port : 'Port ' + port;
    switch (error.code) {
      case 'EACCES':
        console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
        process.exit(1);
        break;
      case 'EADDRINUSE':
        console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
        process.exit(1);
        break;
      default:
        throw error;
    }
  }

  function onListening() {
    const addr = server.address();
    const bind = typeof addr === 'string' ? 'pipe ' + addr : 'port ' + addr.port;
    debug('Listening on ' + bind);
  }

}());
```

Comment: can you please post your node.js code?

Comment: is you node server running on localhost or 192.168.30.5?

Comment: Both scripts (frontend and backend) runs on the same machine (192.168.30.5), but in netstat -nltp  node shows as  :::3132. Ng serve shows as 192.168.30.5:4200